# Android: Save Mediarecorder-Stream as playable file

Tags: android, video, stream, mediarecorder, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I want to record videos with my android device (Nexus 10) and upload it later to youtube.

So far I'am recording with the android MediaRecoder and stream it via LocalSocket to save the data to multiple files. But the files are not playable.

I read some articles that sine API-Level 18 it is possible to convert files with MediaCodec and/or MediaMuxer. And i found this [this](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) code, but i do not really understand how to handle it.

Has anybody an easy example which shows how to convert the raw data from the LocalSocket to a playable file (i.e. mp4 files)?

My MediaRecoder looks like this:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
camcorderProfile_HQ.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
camcorderProfile_HQ.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP;
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
clientSocket = new LocalSocket();
clientSocket.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(SOCKET_ADDRESS));
recorder.setOutputFile(clientSocket.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of writing to clientSocket why no write to a file with .mp4 extension ?

Comment: Why do you say "raw data from the LocalSocket"? Is the output an unmuxed h264?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it like that. Writing to a mp4 muxed file requires the file descriptor to be seekable. Unix sockets are not. This is probably because muxing to mp4 commonly requires the muxer to seek back and forth to write indices etc... and that cannot be done on local sockets.

If you can't simply output to file and then copy it, this might be very interesting for you: http://hello-qd.blogspot.it/2013/05/how-to-process-mediarecorder-frames.html.

Comment: Thanks for for that. But when id do 'extractor.getTrackCount();' i received '0'! Is there something wrong with my file or my MediaRecorder setup? I just saved the stream into a file!

Comment: Can you play the file?

Comment: You can try with this: http://android-chirag.blogspot.it/2012/06/video-recording-example-in-android.html.